# Visual basic dialogue box if pasting over more than one cell in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I don't even know where to start with this one, having a huge mental block.

I need a visual basic sub that activates whenever a value is being pasted into more than one cell - so for example, if I have a list of people on different lines copied and I accidentally paste them so they overwrite and replace the cells underneath them, instead of selecting inside the cell and pasting it all in there.

How do I create a dialogue box to work as an error so it stops this?

Comment: Testing how many cells are in the `Target` argument of the `Worksheet_Change` event would be a good place to start.  Determining whether or not that came from a paste operation is exceedingly difficult.

Comment: VB.NET is not vba.  please fix your tag selections

Comment: @Plutonix done, apologies. I know that I don't know why I tagged it.

Comment: @Comintern - so if I wanted it to raise a dialogue box if it was pasting outside the selected cell?

Comment: Test something like `ActiveCell.Address = Target.Address`.

Comment: [This may be of use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16626134/445425)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would conditionally formatting the column to highlight duplicates be effective for you? It wouldn't show an error message but it could highlight the cells red when duplicates appear...

Comment: The issue is that I'm working with people that accidentally paste over more than one cell and don't realize they're doing it. I want the code to stop them.